# Exit code of thread in Windows C++

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, exit

Suppose I have created multiple threads.
Now I am waiting for multiple object as well using :

```
WaitOnMultipleObject(...);
```

Now if I want to know the status of all the thread's return code. How to do that ?

Do I need to loop for all the thread's handle in the loop.

```
 GetExitCodeThread(
  __in   HANDLE hThread,
  __out  LPDWORD lpExitCode
);
```

And now check `lpExitCode` for success / failure code ?

Cheers,
Siddhartha

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to wait for a thread to exit, just wait on the thread's handle.  Once the wait completes you can get the exit code for that thread.

```
DWORD result = WaitForSingleObject( hThread, INFINITE);

if (result == WAIT_OBJECT_0) {
    // the thread handle is signaled - the thread has terminated
    DWORD exitcode;

    BOOL rc = GetExitCodeThread( hThread, &exitcode);
    if (!rc) {
        // handle error from GetExitCodeThread()...
    }
}
else {
    // the thread handle is not signaled - the thread is still alive
}
```

This example can be extended to waiting for completion of several thread by passing an array of thread handles to `WaitForMultipleObjects()`. Figure out which thread completed using the appropriate offset from `WAIT_OBJECT_0` on the return from `WaitForMultipleObjects()`, and remove that thread handle from the handle array passed to `WaitForMultipleObjects()` when calling it to wait for the next thread completion.

Answer (score 3):

> Do I need to loop for all the thread's
>   handle in the loop.
>
> ```
>  GetExitCodeThread(
>   __in   HANDLE hThread,
>   __out  LPDWORD lpExitCode
> );
> ```

Yes.